# changing tableview height at runtime

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift

Hlo,
I'm creating a menu as a tableview and toggling its visibility on button click. I'm changing its height actually.But changing the height of tableview is affecting only tableview not the cells inside it. TableView also have shadow, if i remove shadow it works perfectly. Please help.
Here is some code fragment

```
let _initialTableFrame = CGRectMake(self.view.frame.size.width - 150, 68, 140, 0)
    _topMenuTableView = UITableView(frame: _initialTableFrame)
    _topMenuTableView.delegate = self
    _topMenuTableView.dataSource = self
    _topMenuTableView.rowHeight = 35
    _topMenuTableView.tag = 100
    _topMenuTableView.alpha = 0.9
    _topMenuTableView.tableFooterView = UIView()
    _topMenuTableView.scrollEnabled = false

    _topMenuTableView.layer.cornerRadius = 5
    _topMenuTableView.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.blackColor().CGColor
    _topMenuTableView.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0, 0)
    _topMenuTableView.layer.shadowRadius = 5.0
    _topMenuTableView.layer.shadowOpacity = 1 
func toogleTopMenu()
{
    if _isTopMenuVisible
    {
        let _currentTopMenuFrame = _topMenuTableView.frame
        let _tempFrame = CGRectMake(_currentTopMenuFrame.origin.x, _currentTopMenuFrame.origin.y, _currentTopMenuFrame.size.width, 0)


        UIView.animateWithDuration(0.2, animations: {self._topMenuTableView.frame = _tempFrame})
        _isTopMenuVisible = false
    }
    else
    {
        let _currentTopMenuFrame = _topMenuTableView.frame
        let _tempFrame = CGRectMake(_currentTopMenuFrame.origin.x, _currentTopMenuFrame.origin.y, _currentTopMenuFrame.size.width, 38)

        UIView.animateWithDuration(0.2, animations: {self._topMenuTableView.frame = _tempFrame})
        _isTopMenuVisible = true
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because you are only changing the frame of tableView not the `tableViewCellHeight`

Try this

```
    func toogleTopMenu()
{
    if _isTopMenuVisible
    {
        let _currentTopMenuFrame = _topMenuTableView.frame
        let _tempFrame = CGRectMake(_currentTopMenuFrame.origin.x, _currentTopMenuFrame.origin.y, _currentTopMenuFrame.size.width, 0)

        UIView.animateWithDuration(0.2, animations: {self._topMenuTableView.frame = _tempFrame
_topMenuTableView.rowHeight = //whatever Height you want to assign
_topMenuTableView.reloadDate()
})

        _isTopMenuVisible = false
    }
    else
    {
        let _currentTopMenuFrame = _topMenuTableView.frame
        let _tempFrame = CGRectMake(_currentTopMenuFrame.origin.x, _currentTopMenuFrame.origin.y, _currentTopMenuFrame.size.width, 38)
    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.2, animations: {self._topMenuTableView.frame = _tempFrame
_topMenuTableView.rowHeight = //whatever Height you want to assign
_topMenuTableView.reloadDate()
})
    _isTopMenuVisible = true
}
}
```

It will help.Thanks